# How to make the minimum value for a column 0 (or prevent decrement_counter from setting negative values)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Tag model with a `posts_count` column which acts as a counter cache for the number of posts a tag has:

**schema.rb:**

```
 t.integer  "posts_count", :default => 0, :null => false
```

**tagging.rb:**

```
 def decrement_tag_counter_cache
    Tag.decrement_counter(:posts_count, self.tag.id) if !post.published? || post.decrement_tag_counters? 
  end
```

**post.rb:**

```
  after_save :increment_decrement_tag_counters # covers :save, :create, :update methods

  def increment_tag_counters? # if status changes and the previous status wasn't "Published"
    status_changed? && changed_attributes["status"] != "Published"
  end

  def decrement_tag_counters? # if status changes and the previous status was "Published"
    status_changed? && changed_attributes["status"] == "Published"
  end

  def increment_decrement_tag_counters
    if published? && increment_tag_counters?
      taggings.each { |tagging| tagging.increment_tag_counter_cache }
    elsif decrement_tag_counters?
      taggings.each { |tagging| tagging.decrement_tag_counter_cache }
    end
  end
```

The problem now is that sometimes, the `decrement_tag_counter_cache` method makes `posts_count` become negative (e.g. -1).

Is there any way of telling Rails: make the minimum value of `posts_count` 0? So that if the current value is 0 and the counter decrements, `posts_count` would still remain 0? Another thing that I could do is to prevent `decrement_counter` from setting negative values. Is that possible?

(This shouldn't work as validation but rather, as a default behavior, since I don't want errors showing up.)

Answer (score 1):

You can put validation on posts_count as follow

```
validates :posts_count, :numericality => { :greater_than_or_equal_to => 0 }
```

Or you can do something like this

```
before_save :set_posts_count

def set_posts_count
  posts_count = 0 if posts_count < 0
end
```

Comment: So if `decrement_count` wants to make `posts_count` -1 it will automatically become 0 without any error (by the way, shouldn't it be `greater_or_equal_than => 0`?

Comment: agreed it should be greater_than_or_equal_to => 0, m not sure about setting the default value but what you can do is to make a method call and set the default value to 0 if there is validation error on posts_count

Comment: here you go another option

Comment: This is strange, I added the first code and I'm still getting `posts_count` with `-1`.

Comment: Muhamamd Awais I even tried the second code: `self.posts_count = 0 if self.posts_count < 0` (I placed it in `tag.rb`) Still getting the negative count.

Comment: i am amazed it should work if you put the validation or before_save call back for posts_count in tagging.rb ?

Comment: you need to get it to return true i think `def set_posts_count ;posts_count = 0 if posts_count < 0 ; true ; end`

Answer (score 0):

The problem may appear because this method, as far as I remember, doesnt initialize the model instance, so it sends a straight sql query like this one :

```
UPDATE "Tags" SET "posts_counter" = COALESCE("posts_counter", 0) - 1 WHERE "Tags"."id" = 5
```

If so, I am not sure how to solve this problem, probably you can initialize a model instance with a lock and then decrement the counter, but locks have its disadvantages

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
[posts_count, 0].max
```